# Postgres - required databases

Tags: postgresql

I have accidentally deleted the default "postgres" database from my postgres. I've read that:

*Most Postgres servers have three databases defined by default: template0 , template1 and postgres . template0 and template1 are skeleton databases that are or can be used by the CREATE DATABASE command. postgres is the default database you will connect to before you have created any other databases.*

I have now created again a postgres database by running CREATE DATABASE postgres.

Do I need to do anything else to basically redo deleting the "postgres" database? Or the current one is basically the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database `postgres` is in no way special.  You should use the bootstrap superuser (normally `postgres`) as the database owner, then the database will be just as good as the original `postgres` database.

The only difference is that the new database will have an OID ≥ 16384, which identifies it as an object created after cluster initialization. However, a quick look through the source code makes me believe that we don't use that anywhere.